# Can Windows 7 recovery iso be used to create a bootable recovery USB?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

Can Windows 7 recovery iso be used to create a bootable recovery USB? If yes, how?

I did try using unetbootin but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have tried it myself, but here's a tutorial: [system-recovery-options-windows-7-recovery-environment-usb-stick.doc](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/13729d1244515057-system-recovery-options-windows-7-recovery-environment-usb-stick.doc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).  This makes installation of the recovery CD simple and easy to do.  Also if you use the multiboot option you can add other bootable iso's to the mix (i.e. ubuntu, memtest86+, boot and nook, just to name a few).