# How to copy windows recovery iso to usb in linux?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bootloader, usb-storage, recovery-console

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Can windows 7 recovery iso be used to create a bootable recovery usb?](https://superuser.com/questions/108088/can-windows-7-recovery-iso-be-used-to-create-a-bootable-recovery-usb)
>
> [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/487970)

I'm trying to restore my windows bootloader after deleting ubuntu.  I have windows 7 recovery iso that I want to burn onto a 2gig usb drive.  How do I do this so that its bootable?  I'm using ubuntu 10.10 live.

Answer (score -1):

You can 'copy' your Windows iso on previously formated (NTFS) pendrive as any other iso (using `dd` for instance) and then write the right boot record using [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) tool.